# C++ shader question

Tags: rendering, shader, wireframe

Suppose I have some geometrical data and I wish to render it in wireframe mode. Obviously, this can be done using the API *(for example, by setting some appropriate mode like `D3DFILL_WIREFRAME` in DirectX).*

*But  I was interested if that is possible to achieve using **vertex / geometry / pixel shaders** (combined, probably).*

Does someone have a sample of that?

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, "C++" is a programming language that is agnostic to anything higher level that would be capable of rendering. It sounds like you're referring to DirectX? Or was that an example, and you're talking about OpenGL? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @EboMike *I was interested if that's actually possible and, obviously, want the shader code for that if it is.* HLSL/GLSL/Cg - it doesn't matter, because it's not that hard to port. Probably, C++ tag is the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like http://wn.com/DirectX_C++__Geometry_with_Wireframe_Effect ?

Try this: http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html -- code at the bottom

```
// ------------------ Vertex Shader --------------------------------
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
void main(void)
{
   gl_Position =  ftransform();
}


// ------------------ Geometry Shader --------------------------------
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable

uniform vec2 WIN_SCALE;
noperspective varying vec3 dist;
void main(void)
{
  vec2 p0 = WIN_SCALE * gl_PositionIn[0].xy/gl_PositionIn[0].w;
  vec2 p1 = WIN_SCALE * gl_PositionIn[1].xy/gl_PositionIn[1].w;
  vec2 p2 = WIN_SCALE * gl_PositionIn[2].xy/gl_PositionIn[2].w;

  vec2 v0 = p2-p1;
  vec2 v1 = p2-p0;
  vec2 v2 = p1-p0;
  float area = abs(v1.x*v2.y - v1.y * v2.x);

  dist = vec3(area/length(v0),0,0);
  gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
  EmitVertex();

  dist = vec3(0,area/length(v1),0);
  gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[1];
  EmitVertex();

  dist = vec3(0,0,area/length(v2));
  gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[2];
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}


// ------------------ Fragment Shader --------------------------------
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable

noperspective varying vec3 dist;
const vec4 WIRE_COL = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1);
const vec4 FILL_COL = vec4(1,1,1,1);

void main(void)
{
    float d = min(dist[0],min(dist[1],dist[2]));
    float I = exp2(-2*d*d);
    gl_FragColor = I*WIRE_COL + (1.0 - I)*FILL_COL;
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, that's it, but I'm looking for shader code so that I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.